# Disabling conflicting code with conditional and a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user is supposed to select an event to attend, but say the user wants to go to an event thats on a Tuesday between 9am-12pm, all other events that conflict with that time during that day need to be disabled and have a text decoration of line-through.

I've tried to loop through the checkboxes already, but what I've tried wont work. Another part of the condition needs to be added (&&) but I'm not sure how to write it.

Heres what I need in the condition:

1. First, does the activity occur at the same day and time as the 
   activity that was just
   clicked? We can check this by seeing if the activity label text 
   contains the above day and
   time variable values.

   2. Second, is the activity different than the activity that was just 
      clicked? We can check this
      by seeing if the activity label text is not equal to the label text 
      of the activity that was
      just clicked.'

I believe I have the first part of the condition correct, but every few clicks, it will give me false when it should be true or vise versa.

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {  
    //Loop through checkboxes with checkboxes[i] . 
    //see if the selected checkbox contains the day and time . 
    //if other checkbox texts contain selected day and time, disable .  
    //and use css to add a line through <label> and <input>  
    /*
    ex: if user selects activity with day Tuesday and time 9am-12pm . 
    all other events with the time 9am-12pm on a Tuesday need to be    
    disabled and put a line through.  
    */
    }

    /*
    bottom code needs to go somewhere in loop to compare date.  
    It also needs another condition (&&) to run the condition  
    correctly, I just dont know what it is yet.  

    Here is the study guide I'm using my issue starts on page 5.

    [Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vw658- 
    9KUiUZ5yHaABvkytC9W2QBYiW_/view) . 
    */
    if (chosenArr.includes(parsedDate)) { . 
    console.log(chosenArr);   
    console.log(parsedDate);   
    console.log(true);   
    return;  
    } else { . 
    console.log(false);  
    } . 

    chosenArr.push(parsedDate);
```

The console should respond true when two events of the same day and time are clicked and false if the time and day don't match up. Clicking different events will return true when thats not the correct output. If i can figure out the other part of the condition, I might be able to get the right output.

Comment: Heres my github file if that helps: https://github.com/joeEscob1023/interactiveForm/blob/master/js/app.js#L16

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Do you run into issues trying to deal *only* with  the date part? I would think you'd need to do a more sophisticated predicate. For example, the time could start before another's but run into its time span. Similarly, the start time could be during another. Are you handling these cases?

Comment: I'm sorry, i just don't know how else to ask it. So theres a set of activities, they each have a day and a time, if the user checks an event, all other events with that time on that day need to be disabled and crossed out. I don't know what logic to use to get that. I have a study guide but i'm kind of confused by it. Ill post it in here, maybe it'll make more sense to you. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vw658-9KUiUZ5yHaABvkytC9W2QBYiW_/view

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Looking at this further, it looks like when a User clicks on a checkbox, you want to disable any other events that conflict. Based on your current layout, this is not easily possible as there is no way to compare the Date or Time of each event since all the data is in the label. You'd have to parse out the date and the Time and compare them logically as Strings.

Answer (score 0):

One way to help this, will be do add `data` attributes to your items that can hold the Start date and time and End start and time of each event. You also have a super condition for the first item that basically should disable all the others.

The following is a basic example that will need to be flushed out further.

```js
$(function() {
  function getTimes(el) {
    var st = Date.parse(el.data("start"));
    var et = Date.parse(el.data("end"));
    return [new Date(st), new Date(et)];
  }

  function compareTimes(a, b) {
    var x = getTimes(a),
      y = getTimes(b);
    if (y[0] >= x[0] && y[0] < x[1]) {
      // Conflict in Start time
      return -1;
    }
    return 1
  }

  function checkOthers(that, p) {
    $("input:checkbox:not([name=all])", p).not(that).each(function(i, el) {
      if (compareTimes(that, $(el)) == -1) {
        $(el).prop("disable", true).parent().addClass("strike");
      } else {
        $(el).prop("disable", false).parent().removeClass("strike");
      }
    });
  }

  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is("[name='all']")) {
      $(".activities input:checkbox").not(this).each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).parent().hasClass("strike")) {
          $(el).prop("disabled", false).parent().removeClass("strike");
        } else {
          $(el).prop("disabled", true).parent().addClass("strike");
        }
      });
    } else {
      checkOthers($(this), $(".activities"));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
input,
button {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font: 1em/1.5;
  color: #184f68;
  background: #accbd9;
}

form {
  padding: .875em 1.875em 1.875em;
  background: #85b5ca;
}

fieldset,
legend,
button {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

fieldset {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

legend,
button {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

legend {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: .5em;
  border-top: 2px solid #679cb3;
  margin-bottom: 1.125em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
legend {
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

label.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input,
select {
  margin-bottom: 1.125em;
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: .8em;
  background: #c1deeb;
  border: 2px solid #c1deeb;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #5e97b0;
  transition: border-color .4s, background-color .4s;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: .55em 1.25em;
  background: #22627e;
  margin: 1.25em 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #184c62;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<fieldset class="activities">
  <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="all" data-start="2019-07-30T9:00:00" data-end="2019-07-31T16:00:00" /> Main Conference — $200</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" data-start="2019-07-30T9:00:00" data-end="2019-07-30T12:00:00" > JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs" data-start="2019-07-30T13:00:00" data-end="2019-07-30T16:00:00" /> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="express" data-start="2019-07-30T9:00:00" data-end="2019-07-30T12:00:00" /> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="node" data-start="2019-07-30T13:00:00" data-end="2019-07-30T16:00:00" /> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools" data-start="2019-07-31T9:00:00" data-end="2019-07-31T12:00:00" /> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="npm" data-start="2019-07-31T13:00:00" data-end="2019-07-31T16:00:00" /> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
</fieldset>
```

You can see the checkboxes now have extra HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" data-start="2019-07-30T9:00:00" data-end="2019-07-30T12:00:00" > JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
```

The data attributes can be called easily using `.data()` and are very useful to bind data to elements. I populated them with the simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`. This can be easily used to parse into a Date object. [See More](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format).

You can capture the data from the String if you really want. I do not recommend it yet you can use a Regular Expression to do that.

When a checkbox is clicked, we need to know if it's the 'all' or if it's an individual event. For all, we can just set all the other events to be disabled. If we uncheck it, we reverse all that. Otherwise we need to know the start and end time of the event selected, and iterate the other, not 'all', items to see if there is a conflict. Most of this is done with `.each()`

Converting dates and times to Date Objects, we can logically compare them with `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, and `>`. This makes it easy to look at if the Start time of an event is between the start and end time of another event.

Hope this helps gets you going.